# jboss7 and HornetQ with asyncio low performance

Tags: jboss, hornetq

I am using jboss7 which has embedded the HornetQ server. I want to use ASYNCIO instead of Java NIO as the bibliography indicates that the ASYNCIO has better performance from the NIO. Although in my measurements when I use NIO the system can transfer 600 messages in the queue per second and when I use ASYNCIO the system  transfers 250 messages per seconds. What can cause this low performance when I use ASYNCIO?

Answer (score 2):

Try increasing the journal sizes... use 10 files of 10 Mib each. If you are using the defaults it's quite low.